# Navmesh bound in ue4 topdown and third person template

Tags: unreal-4

The Topdown template has a navmesh volume to build walkable area, if remove that volume, the character will be unwalkable. However, the third person template has no such thing, but the character movement is OK.

What's the difference between them? Why third person template don't need a navmesh volume?